# PrivateRoute not working with push

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm using PrivateRoute to authenticate if user is logged in or not which is kind of working fine using below code

```
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
    rest.user ? (
        <Component {...props}/>
    ):(
        <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: {from: props.location}
        }}/>
    )
)}/>

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        user: state.user.currentUser,
        routeProps: {
            exact: ownProps.exact,
            path: ownProps.path
        }
    };
};
```

This much works okay but if navigate to any other route which is also 'privated' and click on browser 'Back' button, it just stays on that second page though url in address bar changes. 
If I replace PrivateRoute with Route then everything works fine.
What am I doing wrong here ? This is how routing is setup

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/a" component={ListComponent}/>
<PrivateRoute exact path="/a1" component = { AddContainer } />
<PrivateRoute exact path="/a1/:id" component = { AddContainer } />
```

Comment: Resolved this one. I was missing switch in definition of routes.